# How many ways can two cards be selected from five different cards with replacement when order matters?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So I have $5$ different cards and I am choosing $2$. I want to know the total possible permutations of choosing two cards (I know the answer is $25$ by using permutations).

I need other ways to solve this problem, I get 25 by using $$P(5,2)=\frac{P(5,5)}{P(5,3)}$$ and $$P(5,2)=\frac{P(5,3)P(5,4)}{P(5,5)}$$ 
Do any of the two equations make sense for my case? If they do why do they make sense? Are there other ways of solving my problem without getting way too complicated?

Comment: Are you choosing the cards with replacement or without replacement?  Does the order of selection matter?

Comment: The equations you wrote down are not correct, with the standard interpretation of $P(n,k)$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig With replacement. The order does matter.

Comment: $5\times 5$ is the simplest way. For other ways, for example we can use $P(5,2)+5$. The first term counts the ordered pairs $(x,y)$ where $x\ne y$, and the second term counts the ordered pairs $(x,x)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But 5 x 5 is the same as P(5,2), which is what my solution is.

Comment: I don't know what notation you are using. Something like $P(n,k)$ is used for the count of the number of strings of length $k$ made up of **distinct** elements of a set of size $n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas It is distinct elements; I have 5 different cards and I'm choosing 2. I'm using permutations so $P(n, k)=n^k$ which when 5 and 2 are inputted is $5^2$ which is 5 x 5

Comment: @PeterZhu You are counting permutations with repetition.  However, the notation $P(n, k)$ normally denotes permutations without repetition.  $$P(n, k) = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$$ so $$P(5, 2) = \frac{5!}{(5 - 2)!} = \frac{5!}{3!} = \frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3!}{3!} = 5 \cdot 4 = 20$$

Comment: Maybe your course is using $P(n,k)$ in a non-standard way.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I was not aware of that. How would I denote permutation with repetition?

Comment: @AndréNicolas N. F. Taussing just made it aware to me that I have been using the notation in the wrong way. I am really sorry for the confusion. I meant permutations with repetition, not without repetition as I was denoting with my formula.

Comment: For this kind of situation, there is no special notation for the number of permutations with repetition, since no special notation is needed: the number is $n^k$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Alright thanks. So back to the question, are there other ways to calculate this? I need to represent this calculation in as many ways as possible.

Comment: I gave one way in an earlier comment.

Comment: @AndréNicolas In class we learned about Direct (find the total possible outcomes) and Indirect (total possible outcomes subtracted by unsuitable outcomes) reasoning. My way is direct reasoning, is there some way to solve this by using indirect reasoning?

Comment: In this case any kind of counting the complement would be excessively complicated.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I have two ways that equal to 25: $\frac{5^5}{5^3}$ and $\frac{5^3*5^4}{5^5}$. Does any of these two ways make any sense or are they purely coincidental that they equal to 25?

Comment: I can find a combinatorial interpretation for the first, make all strings of length $5$ and consider two strings to be equivalent if their first two terms are equal. So each equivalence class has $5^3$ elements, and therefore there are $\frac{5^5}{5^3}$ possibilities for the first two terms. But it is a stretch! Are you sure you are supposed to do this for with replacement?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am doing it with replacement. Do you know any other ways that are simpler? We haven't learned what you are talking about (at least I don't think so).

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, $5^2$ is simplest. Reasonably simple is $(5)(4)+5$, with the reasoning described above. Or equivalently use $2\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{1}$.